# Is there a concise way (without loops) to create a linearly spaced array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I'd like to create an array of numbers, 80 to 86, separated by increments of 0.5. I know I can create an array to represent this by writing

```
float Vector1[] = {80, 80.5, 81, 81.5, 82, 82.5, 83, 83.5, 84, 84.5, 85, 85.5, 86};
```

In Matlab, which is what I normally use, this is simply

```
Vector1 = 80:0.5:86;
```

In this particular case, it's not a big deal to write the array manually, but for a larger array it wouldn't be feasible to write out every entry. Is there similar functionality in C to create linearly spaced one-dimensional arrays of arbitrary bounds and step size? As stated in the title, I'd like to know if there's a solution that doesn't involve using a loop.

Comment: No.You can't do that in C without using loop.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Saving typing? Avoiding typos? Minimising length of source code?

Comment: "I'd like to know if there's a solution that doesn't involve using a loop." Why? This is exactly what loops are for. Your matlab command uses a loop under the covers.

Comment: Recursion could do...

Comment: @Yunnosch Saving typing, primarily. It's much easier to write an array containing 10,000 numbers as `a = 1:10000` instead of writing a loop to do the same thing.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Iterative or recursive, a loop is a loop.

Comment: @zaen Luckily C has functions, so you only need to write it once. :)

Comment: @unwind I see recursion more like spiral :)

Comment: Usually, when you think you need such an array, you don't actually need an array.

Comment: Did you consider implementing a code generator, which will avoid the typing, but in the end you still have a non-nonsense old-style initialisation of an array. I am by the way with Eugene comment above. You might not need anything as regular as this in an array. I assume however, that there is more behind. Nevertheless, please check the concept of a XY-problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible without loops.All languages which offer functionality that you have asked uses a loop to achieve it.In C you just have to write your own.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say [*not possible*](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KIrgnqtz1mFDSN3i), but sure a loop is better and probably, as others noted, an array is not even needed.

Comment: yeah you are right,it can be achieved via recursion also but like u have said a loop is more efficient

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because it answers my question directly: "No, there's essentially no way to do this without a loop" was what I was looking for in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a separate piece of code that generates the static declaration:

makevector.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float i;
    int first = 1;
    printf("float Vector1[] = { ");
    for (i = 80; i <= 86; i += 0.5) {
        if (first) {
            first = 0;
        } else {
            printf(", ");
        }
        printf("%.1f", i);
    }
    printf(" };\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then run it:

```
gcc -o makevector makevector.c
./makevector > vector.c
```

While technically you still have a loop, it's done ahead of time to create code so that you don't need a loop in your real code.

Comment: `i += 0.5` is fortunate as 0.5 is exact.  Had it been `0.1`, using a loop with an integer loop count up to `n`, such as `n = lround((hi-lo)/delta);`, may be preferable to handle the usual FP issues.  Still this is a good answer.

Comment: @chux Correct.  Had the increment been some other value I would have recommended something slightly different.